# When are two quotient Topologies homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a path connected space. If $S$ and $R$ are two equivalence relations on $X$, then one knows that $X/S$ and $X/R$ are path connected. Assume $S \subset R$, i.e $\forall x_{1},x_{2}\in X$, one has $  x_{1}Sx_{2}\implies x_{1}Rx_{2}$.
Now suppose $s_{1},s_{2}\in X/S$ ,$s_{1} \ne s_{2}$, are such that there exists a path $\Gamma$ in $X/S$ from $s_{1}$ to $s_{2}$ that maps to a constant path in $X/R$. Does this allow one to extend the relation $S$ to $S'$ in a way that $S\subsetneq S' \subset R$ and $$X/S\cong X/S'?$$

For Example

On $I^{2}$ Let S be given by $(t,0)∼(t,1)$, $(0,t_{1})∼(0,t_{2})$ and $(1,t_{1})∼(1,t_{2})$ ∀t,$t_{1},t_{2}∈I$. Let $R$ identify $∂I^{2}$. Both $X/R$ and $X/S$ are $S^{2}$, and there is a path $Γ$ with said property. There are various extensions $S′$, the maximal one being simply $R$. I am wondering if this is possible even in cases when $X/R$ and $X/S$ need not be homeomorphic, but one can find a maximal $S′$ based on just the existence of $Γ$.

Comment: Do you mean $X/R\cong X/S'$?

Comment: I don't have a proof but if you take $X=S^1\lor S^1$ (two circles attached by one point). You take $S$ to be the trivial relation and $R$ to identify each point in one circle to the other. It seems like you can't find a strictly smaller equivalence relation $S'$ such that $X/S' \cong S^1$.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "lfting a path". We have a map $\phi : X/S \to X/R$. Given a path $u$ in $X/S$, what would be the lift to $X/R$? Simply $\phi u $?

Comment: "Now suppose $s_{1},s_{2}\in X/S$ are such that there exists a path $\Gamma$ in $X/S$ from $s_{1}$ to $s_{2}$ that lifts to a constant path in $X/R$." What if this is never satisfied?